# simple calculator with javascript and it function calculator doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am new to Javascript so this is probably an easy fix but I cannot figure out. I am making a calculator using HTML, CSS and Javascript
and I pretty much only know about declaration, if/else statement, for/while loops and some basic elements of CSS and HTML.

here is my javascript code for the calculator.

```
var firstNum, operator, previousKey, previousNum;

const calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator'); 
const buttons = calculator.querySelector('.calculator__buttons'); 
const display = document.querySelector('.calculator__display');


function calculate(n1, operator, n2) {
  let result = '';
  
  if(operator === '+'){
    result = n1 + n2;
  }else if(operator === '-'){
    result = n1 - n2;
  }else if(operator === '*'){
    result = n1 * n2;
  }else if(operator === '/'){
    result = n1 / n2;
  }
   return result;
}


buttons.addEventListener('click', function (event) {


  const target = event.target; 
  const action = target.classList[0];
  const buttonContent = target.textContent; 
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    
    
    let firstNum = 0;
    if (action === 'number') {
      
      if (display.textContent > 0 ) {
        display.textContent += buttonContent //
      }
      else {display.textContent = buttonContent}
      
      //display.textContent = buttonContent
      console.log('number1 ' + buttonContent + ' button1');
      previousKey = 'number';
    }

    if (action === 'operator') {
      console.log('operator1 ' + buttonContent + ' button1');
      operator = buttonContent;
      firstNum = display.textContent
      //console.log(firstNum) 
      return firstNum
      previousKey = 'operator';
    }

    if (action === 'decimal') {
      // console.log('deciaml1');
      previousKey = 'decimal';
    }

    if (action === 'clear') {
      display.textContent = '0'
      console.log('clear1');
      previousKey = 'clear';
    }

    if (action === 'calculate') {
      console.log('caculate1');
      display.textContent = calculate(firstNum, operator, display.textContent)
      previousKey = 'calculate';
    }
  }
});
```

although I set arithmetic operations above as function calculate(n1, operator, n2)

[my caculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiDL9.png) // here is what it looks like.

result of 5-9 comes out as -59.
I will appreciate if I could get some help.
thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please accept the answer if it solves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are sending in strings to the calculate function. So you should explicitly convert the string textContent to integer values as such in your code:

```
if (action === 'calculate') {
      console.log('caculate1');
      display.textContent = calculate(parseInt(firstNum,10), operator, parseInt(display.textContent,10))
      previousKey = 'calculate';
}
```

Comment: thank you for kindly taking your time and answer my question.
Following up on your answer,
why is the integer value set to 10 (when could have been any number?) 
and on chrome inspect - console, after typing 4-3 enter; error message "ParseInt is not defined" appears.
where in my code should I fix in order for it to function? 

Thank you in advance

Comment: my mistake (parseInt; typo)

Here is another question though, 

I have changed my code and the calculator function still doesn't work....

Comment: what is the answer for 5-9 now? @EmilyScone

Comment: nothing returned. (not even NaN or -59)
so instead, I set the last part back to how it was 
```
 if (action === 'calculate') {
      console.log('caculate1');
      display.textContent = calculate(firstNum, operator, display.textContent)
      previousKey = 'calculate';
    }
```

Comment: ```
function calculate(n1, operator, n2) {
  let result = '';
    if(operator === '+'){
    result = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
  }else if(operator === '-'){
    result = parseFloat(n1) - parseFloat(n2);
  }else if(operator === '*'){
    result = parseFloat(n1) * parseFloat(n2);
  }else if(operator === '/'){
    result = parseFloat(n1) / parseFloat(n2);
  }
   return result;
}
```
and defined integer values in every strings above.
perhaps the answer for 5-9 still -59 but on the bright side, at least some value returns. again thank you for your time. @berlin

Comment: could you do two things, 
1. do ```console.log(calculate(parseInt(firstNum,10), operator, parseInt(display.textContent,10))```
2. put a console.log inside the '-' conditional to check that we are entering that specific part of the function